# boost::regex and the word character class (\W and \w)

Tags: c++, regex, boost

From the documentation:

> *"\W" matches any single character that is not a member of the "word" character class*

It looks like the boost::regex library, by default supposes *the "word" character class* as any character, even **non-Latin** (+ digits).

The question is how to set for the boost::regex library the "word" character class as **Latin only** characters + digits?

Answer (score 1):

If ICU enabled this `\w(?<=\p{Block=Basic_Latin})`
if not then this `\w(?<=[\x{0}-\x{7e}])`